# module: duplicate definiton for identifier in: x

Tags: racket

I typed this code in Dr Racket running on Linux Mint:

```
lang racket

(define x 2)
(define x 3)
```

and it shows me this:

```
module: duplicate definiton for identifier in: x
```

What should I do to be able to redefine a variable?
(Initially my code was longer but even only this part alone generates error)

Comment: This is not Haskell. Nor would it make sense to type Haskell in Dr Racket. (And FWIW, if it were Haskell then the answer would be _you can't redefine a variable in Haskell_.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to do Haskell, then use GHCi (or [tryhaskell.org](https://tryhaskell.org/)). Use Dr Racket if you want to do Racket.

Answer (score 3):

In Racket `define` is used to declare a variable and at the same time set it to a value. To set the variable to a new value, use `set!`.

```
#lang racket
(define x 2)
(set! x 3)
x
```

Comment: ...but don't ever do that. #functionalrage